# Ninject binding to IKernel fails in ApiController with error "Error loading Ninject component ICache"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have the following simple ApiController example that is failing.

```
public class TestAPIController : ApiController
{
    public TestAPIController(IKernel kernel) { }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "success! " + DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("F");
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.

I have the package Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver installed but it is still failing.

Here is my CreateKernel class in NinjectWebCommon:

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {        
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new VBNinjectModule());
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);

        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new VBNinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
```

Using:

Ninject 3.0.1.10

Ninject.MVC3 3.0.0.6

Ninject.Web.Common: 3.0.0.7

Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver 0.1.4758.24814

Thanks in advance for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: I think ninject auto-binds IKernel (or was it IResolutionRoot?), you should not need to bind it. Injection of Func factory works automatically, you don't need to specify a .Bind<Func<IFoo>>() (as long as there is a binding for IFoo) anyway. Also try injecting IResolutionRoot.

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to inject IKernel to a controller. Instead, you want to register your service, and inject that service to the controller.

```
private static IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
    kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

    RegisterServices(kernel);

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = 
       new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

    return kernel;
}

private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMyService>().To<MyService>().InRequestScope();
}      

// Your api controller
public class TestAPIController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService ;

    public TestAPIController(IMyService myService) 
    { 
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

Comment: Win, thanks for the response.  We are binding everything inside the VBNinjectModule() class.  Where i want the IKernel directly is that some of my code uses reflection to instantiate objects and instead of using Activator.CreateInstance() I want to use kernel.Get<MyService>() so that all the dependencies of MyService will be injected as well.

Comment: IKernel implements IBindingRoot and IResolutionRoot, for instanciation IResolutionRoot suffices.

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried putting IResolutionRoot in the constructor but I get the same error.